# SPARQL select statements where value might not exists

Tags: sparql

I am trying to select data from a query but it will only work when all the data exists.

I am new to SPARQL and can't seem to get the optional parts of my query working.

```
    PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?label ?computingPlatform ?developer ?genre ?publisher ?releaseDate ?series 
WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> rdfs:label ?label . 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:computingPlatform ?computingPlatform . 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:developer ?developer . 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:genre ?genre . 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:publisher ?publisher . 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:releaseDate ?releaseDate . 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:series ?series . 
}
```

So looking at the above if for example "developer" didn't exist on the resource the query would return no results.

Comment: using an `OPTIONAL` pattern for each optional triple pattern is the way to go, see specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#optionals

Comment: there is also no need to repeat the subject URI for each triple pattern, instead you should bind the URI to a variable once and use that variable

Answer (score 0):

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?label ?computingPlatform ?developer ?genre ?publisher ?releaseDate ?series 
WHERE {
    OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> rdfs:label ?label .} 
    OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:computingPlatform ?computingPlatform .}
    OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:developer ?developer .}
    OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:genre ?genre .} 
    OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:publisher ?publisher .}
    OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:releaseDate ?releaseDate .}
    OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring> dbo:series ?series .}
}
```

Comment: `PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?label ?computingPlatform ?developer ?genre ?publisher ?releaseDate ?series 
WHERE {
VALUES ?s {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Elden_Ring>}
?s rdfs:label ?label . FILTER(lang(?label) = "en")
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:computingPlatform ?computingPlatform .}
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:developer ?developer .}
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:genre ?genre .} 
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:publisher ?publisher .}
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:releaseDate ?releaseDate .}
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:series ?series .}
}`